# Where find the Windows 10 update error log?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

I've download the Windows 10 upgrade and started to install it. After about 22%,  I took a break and when I came back Windows 7 was started again.

I'm wondering why Windows 10 did not install and stopped, but I don't know how and where I can take a look at the error log.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Check this: http://superuser.com/questions/494846/windows-8-upgrade-failed-no-error-info

Comment: thank you, I followed the link, but the given answer is way to  cryptic for me

Comment: What part?  Its just a list of log files and the location you can find them at?

Comment: Richard, you want what's located in "**C:\Windows\WindowsUpdate.log**" based on your wording and my interpretation. Let me know if this helps you out... Errors related to Windows Update will be located in this file, and what you see in there related to the Windows 10 update errors, etc. should give you a starting point as well.

Comment: look here C:\$windows.~bt\Sources\Panther

Answer (score 2):

Windows Update logs are now generated using ETW (Event Tracing for Windows).

Please run the `Get-WindowsUpdateLog` PowerShell command to convert ETW traces into a readable WindowsUpdate.log.

For more information, please visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=518345